# what does react compiler mean actually?

Tags: reactjs, compiler-construction

So, recently React announced addition of Compiler for their framework, I am just wondering what they mean in compiler? is it classical compiler that translates from one language to some target language, or does it mean something different? what this would result in?

So, I know some staff about compilers, but I think this isn't compiler in a classical sense, so I was wondering to get any insights about the idea and meaning behind react compiler.

Comment: They mean it's a compile-time step which takes your code as input, and then outputs code that has the same end behavior but is more performant.

Comment: is output of the compiler same language or some other language, so if it's same language, I assume as you've told me that compiler tries to optimize the code I've already written.

Comment: Javascript in, javascript out.

Comment: thanks! pretty interesting idea that target language is the same language but the optimized one.